# How to Make a .xml file for Esri shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, xml, metadata

Mostly for my work I use PostgreSQL or .tab files (MapInfo).
However, I am familiar with conversion from one format to another using `ogr2ogr`.
My problem is that how can I make the metdata file or .xml file for a shapefile.
I converted it using ogr2ogr and QGIS, but none of them makes the .xml file with it.

How can I make shapefile metatdata?

I can use any software including esri for that, just need to know how.

Comment: For what purpose do you need such .xml file?

Comment: I am trying to convert postgresql table to shapefile...

Comment: For shapefiles you must have three parts .shp, .shx, and .dbf. All above that is optional.

Comment: I want to store the metadata of the shapefile in the .xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xml:lang="tr"><Esri><CreaDate>20161206</CreaDate><CreaTime>15344700</CreaTime><ArcGISFormat>1.0</ArcGISFormat><SyncOnce>FALSE</SyncOnce><DataProperties><itemPro.... here is a sample I got from a cllient

Comment: Please **edit the question** to add clarification requested in comments.

Comment: Please review the ArcGIS documentation on metadata. It is trivially simple to create Esri metadata using Esri tools. It's a different problem to generate Esri metadata without Esri software.

Comment: I should note that there's a ***huge*** difference between populating a trivial `.shp.xml` file and populating *actual* metadata. Purists might argue that it's better to not have any XML file if it isn't accurate and complete.

Comment: @IbadRaza: Which reply matched what you were looking for? Please accept the passing answer ; else maybe comment further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS tool [Synchronize Metadata](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/synchronize-metadata.htm) will do this for you (Conversion toolbox).

Be aware that it will create ESRI metadata, a standard that covers fields from many different standards (ref [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/metadata/the-arcgis-metadata-format.htm)). If you need metadata in another standard (FGDC, ISO, Inspire, etc.) you will need to follow up with the [Esri Metadata Translator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/esri-metadata-translator.htm) tool (Conversion toolbox).

Answer (score 0):

This question has been changed after my answer, so this answer is for making the metadata outside of Esri products.

The FGDC has a Geospatial Metadata Tools page with links to some free and commercial software tools for doing this.

https://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/geospatial-metadata-tools

Comment: @Hélène, the question clearly notes "any software", not just Esri.

Comment: my apologies! I read too fast something along "I can use any software within esri". duh. I deleted my comment ; apologies again.

Answer (score 0):

You can export an XML workspace document from a geodatabase, including metadata. First you will need to export your shapefile to a geodatabase, though.

See:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/exporting-a-geodatabase-schema-to-an-xml-workspace-document.htm

Comment: The question is asking about generating a `.shp.xml` metadata file to go *with* a shapefile, not converting the shapefile *into* XML.